# Wet pre-sprouted seed potatoes, is there an hurry to plant them?

Tags: seeds, planting, water, potatoes

I inadvertently left pre-sprouted seed potatoes on my balcony and they suffered a severe shower today.  I didn't plan to plant them before 4 days at the very least.

**Is there an hurry to plant them now that they are wet ?**

They are currently laying spread out in a wood crate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is plenty of air circulation so they dried fairly quickly, I don't think there is anything to worry about.

You might want to move the potatoes out of the crate and keep them "upside down" somewhere for a few hours, to make sure both the potatoes and the bottom of the crate get properly dry.